# What process handles Force Touch?

Tags: macos, mac, trackpad, high-sierra

The Force Touch (URL previews and word definisions) of the trackpad of my MacBook Pro 13" TouchBar often stops working and it works again after a reboot, but I'd like to find a quicker way to make it work again.

What's the process that handles Force Touch on macOS? Then I could try to kill it and see if it works again after restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find the process, but I found out that **if the force touch issue is limited to Safari, just restarting it fixed the issue** in my case. I guess having multiple days of uptime does have some drawback once in a while.